# nytime API returns no data

Tags: api, web-scraping, python-3.5

I am using NYTimes [API](http://developer.nytimes.com/article_search_v2.json) to scrap news articles for my text analysis. Here is the code.

```
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI
api = articleAPI('<API key>')
articles = api.search(q = 'President',
               fq = {'source':['Reuters','AP', 'The New York Times']},
               begin_date = 20110829,
               end_date = 20161203)
print ("the response is ", articles)
```

However, it does not return any results. This is the sample response with null dataset:

> {'response': {'meta': {'offset': 0, 'time': 227, 'hits': 0}, 'docs':
>   []}, 'status': 'OK', 'copyright': 'Copyright (c) 2013 The New York
>   Times Company.  All Rights Reserved.'}

Should there be any additional paremeters when sending the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was using a completely different API in my initial code. Using "requests" API solved the problem here

```
uri = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/archive/v1/"+str(year)+"/"+str(month)+".json?api-key=<>"
resp = requests.get(uri)
```